# Fusion table ajax query with extra parameters

Tags: jquery, google-fusion-tables

I'm querying a google fusion table via jquery ajax:

```
var queryUrlStart = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
var queryUrlEnd = '&jsonCallback=?'; // ? could be a function name
var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + this.tableId;
if (where !== undefined) {
    sql += " WHERE " + where;
}
sql += " ORDER BY '" + _scaleRow.name + "' DESC";

var queryUrl = encodeURI(queryUrlStart + sql + queryUrlEnd);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    context: this,
    url: queryUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: this.handleData
});
```

I'd like to be able to know which table is being queried so I'd like to add an extra parameter to identify it. I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    context: this,
    data: {'table' : this.tableId}
    url: queryUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: this.handleData
});
```

But I don't see it anywhere where I can retrieve `table`

Comment: data: ... will just send data to the server. Will not affect what's returned. Have you tried this.tableId w/in your handleData ? One solution would be to add a column to your Fusion Tables 'table_id' which would be returned via SELECT *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be different ways, e.g. the following:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    url: queryUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend:(function(data){return function(jqXhr){jqXhr.data=data}})
               ({'table' : this.tableId}),
    success: this.handleData
});
```

It uses the beforeSend-method to add a new property to the jqXhr-object. The jqXhr-object may be accessed in the success-callback(it's the 3rd argument), so this would be an example for your success-callback:

```
handleData=function(data,status,jqXhr){
             alert('results for table:'+jqXhr.data.table);
           };
```